# Give editor ability to edit custom settings without access to Main Settings

Tags: user-roles

I have created a custom settings page that I've positioned in tools > Custom Settings

```
add_action('admin_init', array('siteSettings', 'register'));
add_action('admin_menu', array('siteSettings', 'menu'));

$page = add_management_page(PLUGIN_NICK.' Plugin Options', PLUGIN_NICK, 'delete_posts', PLUGIN_ID.'_options', array('siteSettings', 'showPage'));

<form action="options.php"
```

The form posts to options.php (even though I've put it in tools menu), and the editor role gets permission died when trying to update the form, although they can access the form without errors, they just can't save.

I fixed this with

```
$editor = get_role('editor');
$editor->add_cap('manage_options');
```

However this gives them menu items; Appearance, Settings, and all other admin menus created by plugins which I don't want (I only want them to be able to access things in Tools which they had before).

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Use the [Settings API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API) or hook a function to admin_init that checks permissions and nonces, saves the updated values and redirects to the custom settings page.

Comment: I don't understand why you would vote down an answer that actually works and solves the problem?